# Oracle 12.2 Materialized View Enable On Query Computation

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I am trying to use Real Time MV in Oracle 12.2, and want to use real time capabilities

The following code keeps giving error:

```
ORA-32361: cannot ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION for the materialized view

-- create table
drop table cdt
/
create table cdt
(
    id      number primary key,
    name    varchar2(10)
)
/
create materialized view log on cdt
with
rowid,
primary key
including new values
/
create materialized view cdt_mv1
refresh fast on demand
enable query rewrite
enable on query computation
as
   select
        id, name
   from
cdt
/
-- drop materialized view cdt_mv1;
-- drop materialized view log on cdt;
```

Comment: Are you using Enterprise Edition?  Not all types of materialized views work on all editions.

Comment: Yes - Enterprise edition